# Is the number of processes limited by the size of RAM?

Tags: linux, process, stack

Is the number of processes limited by the size of RAM? I saw an article [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/node/3814/print) said: In 2.3.x, it (number of processes) is a tunable parameter which defaults to **size-of-memory-in-the-system / kernel-stack-size**. And since the stack size is 8KB in Linux, can we say that the **number-of-processes = total-stack-size-in-kernel / 8KB** ?

Comment: @Tony , could you help with this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The number of processes is probably dependent on the amount of RAM, but I think it's the processor and the number of cores it has that determines how well each process performs.

Comment: It wouldn't be uncommon to have processes waiting on blocking syscalls; those wouldn't really count in terms of cpu usage except when they wake up.

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between "limited by" and "determined by".  You could fit a HUGE process table into today's multi-gig machines, but they might size that table as a function of RAM.